# Does Simmering peppers in oil bring out more flavor?

Tags: spicy-hot, hot-sauce, infusion

If I simmer a melange of sweet and hot peppers in peanut oil, will it bring out more flavor?  Chemically, what is the result of gently simmering veggies in oil?

My intuition is to first brown onions, garlic, sweet peppers and various hot peppers in bacon grease till aromatic. Then add the mixture to simmering peanut oil and simmer for a long time (several hours). Then let cool and refrigerate for long time (over night to 2 weeks). I'd think this would create a deliciously flavorful and spicy oil.

Maybe even strain out the peppers and blend the peppers to make into a hot sauce? After this simmering process, will there be any interesting flavors left in the peppers?

Comment: Capsaicins boil at 210 to 220 °C (410 to 428 °F) I've gotten them that hot, and it leads to evacuating the house. Use some caution. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capsaicin

Comment: I went ahead and did this and it is delicious (and hot!) I left the peppers in for now, but tasted a few and they were great as well. By accident I was out of the house doing work,  so never found out if the fumes were unbearable. Maybe it wasn't that bad since there were a lot of sweet peppers as well?

Comment: -You pretty much have to walk out of the kitchen with the burner on high for 8 minutes to get oil that hot. At 410°F, most oils are smoking.